# GMail API decoding messages from everywhere

Tags: python, encoding, gmail, gmail-api, quoted-printable

I am working with the GMail API in Python to retrieve mails written in french and I'm actually having a problem with accents.

I retrieve the messages with this :

```
 message = service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=i, format="raw").execute()
```

All I want is to get the body of the mail so I start with this :

```
base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
```

For some mails, it works, I retrieve all the mail data including french text like :

```
"Cette semaine, vous vous êtes servis du module de révision 0 fois"
```

For some others, I get quoted-print encoding, like this :

```
"Salut, =E7a farte?"
```

Quoted-print encoding is no issue as I have built a simple decoding function using the `quopri` module. The main problem here is that the last sentence is wrong for quoted-print encoding, the encoded character is `ç` and should be encoded like this :

```
"Salut, =C3=A7a farte?"
```

So with the wrong encoded sentence, I end-up with this kind of stuff :

```
Salut, �a farte?
```

I suspect the origin being the different mailing client, my first exemple is a message sent from Gmail client to an Outlook address and the second example being the opposite; An outlook message to a Gmail address.

My question here would be, is there a way to handle decoding for any possible scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while `quopri` correctly translates the mail body from 7-bit data to 8-bit data, the encoding that you then use to convert this bytestring into a unicode string is not the right one. In your example, it appears to be ISO-8859-1:

```python
In [1]: import quopri

In [2]: quopri.decodestring('Salut, =E7a farte?').decode('iso-8859-1')
Out[2]: 'Salut, ça farte?'
```

Usually you should be able to get the correct encoding using the `Content-Type` header. This is how it looks like in a mail that uses quoted-printable UTF-8 encoding:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=i).execute()
content = message['payload']['body']['data']
print(base64.b64decode(content).decode('utf-8'))
```

This will get the content of email.

Comment: I tried using this. I found the html part of the email by using content = message['payload']['parts'][0]['parts'][1]['body']['data']. However then I get an error if I try to display it correctly:  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 16: invalid start byte